# Fatal Error in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I Just begin with Laravel 5 and When I try to run `php artisan route:list` to get the liste route, I get this error message :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /var/www/laravel5/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php on line 1

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                           
  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script
```

UserController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    protected $userRepository;

    protected $nbrPerPage = 4;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->userRepository->getPaginate($this->nbrPerPage);
        $links = $users->setPath('')->render());

        return view('index', compact('users', 'links'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(UserCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->store($request->all());

        return redirect('user')->withOk("L'utilisateur " . $user->name . " a été créé.");
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->getById($id);

        return view('show',  compact('user'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->getById($id);

        return view('edit',  compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $this->userRepository->update($id, $request->all());

        return redirect('user')->withOk("L'utilisateur " . $request->input('name') . " a été modifié.");
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->userRepository->destroy($id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

So when I used userController.php generated by `php artisan make:controller UserController` I didn't get error. This is when I override the default controller by adding `__construct()`

Comment: Is the error only when you do `route:list` or does the controller also not work at all?

Comment: I get this error also when i try with this route in firefox : http://localhost/laravel5/public/index.php/user

Comment: And you're 100% certain that what you've pasted in this question is the exact code that's failing? No omitted lines or missing stuff?

Comment: Yes, I'm following a french tuto on "OpenClassroom" and I just re-try with th code from tuto, I get the ssame error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this issue, In my case I just removed all blank spaces before `<?php` and my problem was resolved.

Comment: But, I have not blank spaces befor `<?php`

Comment: @Bissap I just checked again, and in my case this issie is coming as i said. You can check space in all controller

Answer (score 1):

namespace App\Http\Controllers; it should be on first line and 
in your user controller after namespace add the below line

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

and Try to execute command now it will work!!

Comment: I just add `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` after namespace but i get same error...nothing happend.